# What is the mistake in the given code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> A company decides to give bonus to the employees. A 5% bonus is given to the male worker and 10% to female worker. If the salary  of the employee is less than 10000 then the employee gets a 2% extra bonus.
>
> Calculate the salary along with bonus that has to be given.

My code looks like this:

```
a = input('Enter your name here: ')
b = int(input('your salary here: '))
c = input('your gender here (M/F) : ')
if b < 10000 and c == 'M':
    print(str(a) + ' your salary with bonus is ' + str(b * 1.07))
elif b < 10000 and c == 'F':
    print(str(a) + ' your salary with bonus is ' + str(b * 1.12))

if b >= 10000 and c == 'M':
    print(str(a) + ' your salary with  bonus is '+ str(b * 1.05))

elif b >= 10000 and c=='F':
        print(str(a) + ' your salary with  bonus is '+ str(b * 1.1))
```

Comment: What *is* the mistake? Please provide some sample input, and then tell us what output you are getting and what output you expect. [This page](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you you can't just type:

```
if b<10000 and c=='M'  :
    # code
else:
b<10000 and c=='F'
```

If you want to check two conditions, you need two ifs, like so:

```
if b<10000 and c=='M'  :
    # code
else:
  if b<10000 and c=='F' :
    # code
```

Comment: The percentage is applied on the base salary. So the addition part of percentages is alright. I have made some syntax error so kindly tell me that !

Comment: Thank you .So i need to use directly  elif . Right?